# why it float left is not working and these codes

Tags: php, css

my question is that why float left is not working under these codes 
when i use them all the result just display on single div and other 7 where showing under that div at same place so please tell me what is the solution of this prob

```
<div class="tv_l" style="top:1465px;
left:10px;

position:absolute;

width:1690px;
height:10px;
border-radius:3px/3px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:px;
border-left:10px;">

<hr>
</div>


<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "***" ,"***" , "***");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo mysqli_connect_error();
 exit();
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM **** ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8" )
or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )){
?>;



<div class="son_s_p" style="top:1957px;
left:12px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
position:inherit;
background:white;
width:190px;
height:240px;
border-radius:3px/3px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:px;
border-left:10px;
text-align:center;
float:left;

">



 <img src="../lu/music/tumb/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>"style="width:198px; height:148px;"  >
<br>

 <?php echo $row['name']; ?><br><br>

 <div id="son_s_p" style="top:218px;
left:px;

position:absolute;


border-radius:3px/3px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:px;
border-left:10px;
text-align:justify;">


&nbsp;<?php echo $row['time']; ?> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="time&amp;type" style="top;10px;"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></span> 

</div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

[with using position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys47C.png)

[without using position data will go top and top do not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc05s.png)

Comment: Well that might be mostly due to that you are absolutely positioning stuff all over the place, apparently without a clue how that actually works. Also, this is not a PHP problem; and no one here has your database behind this available to reproduce the issue - so the only sensible example here would be one that shows the final HTML code. Please go read [ask], and also how to create a [mcve].

Comment: but when i remove the absolutely it just go in the top and top doesn't work any more

Comment: @FaizgullWaleed Could you show an example of your desired output? Do you want all the divs next to each other?

Comment: i upload the img

Answer (score 0):

your wrong is that you put in div "float: left;" and thats wrong.you should put before it style attribute and it is `Style="float: left;"`

correct code is:

```
<div class="tv_l" style="top:1465px;
left:10px;

position:absolute;

width:1690px;
height:10px;
border-radius:3px/3px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:px;
border-left:10px;">

<hr>
</div>


<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "***" ,"***" , "***");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo mysqli_connect_error();
 exit();
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM **** ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8" )
or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )){
?>;



<div class="son_s_p" style="top:1957px;
left:12px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
position:inherit;
background:white;
width:190px;
height:240px;
border-radius:3px/3px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:px;
border-left:10px;
text-align:center;
float:left;

">



 <img src="../lu/music/tumb/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>"style="width:198px; height:148px;"  >
<br>

 <?php echo $row['name']; ?><br><br>

 <div id="son_s_p" style="top:218px;
left:px;

position:absolute;


border-radius:3px/3px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:px;
border-left:10px;
text-align:justify;">


&nbsp;<?php echo $row['time']; ?> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="time&amp;type" style="top;10px;"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></span> 

</div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: same result check the images plz

Answer (score 0):

Your question was unclear, however I have cleaned up your code so that the div `.tv_l` is to the left of the div `.son_s_p` and its content:

```css
.tv_l {
  border-radius: 3px/3px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

.son_s_p {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  background: white;
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 3px/3px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#son_s_p {
  border-radius: 3px/3px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: px;
  border-left: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="tv_l">
   <hr>
</div>

<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "***" ,"***" , "***");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo mysqli_connect_error();
   exit();
}else{
   echo "";
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM **** ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8")
or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )){
?>

<div class="son_s_p">
   <img src="../lu/music/tumb/<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" style="width:198px; height:148px;">
   <br>
   <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div id="son_s_p">
      <?php echo $row['time']; ?>
      <span class="time&amp;type" style="top;10px;"><?php echo $row['type']; ?></span>
   </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using absolute positioning on your DIVs. Floats cannot work that way. Use this instead:

```
position: static; 
float: left;
```

If I were you I would first try to get it to work with pure HTML and CSS with some dummy data, before hooking it up to the database.

Here's an example of how you can achieve floating with divs, in contrast to your approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/19zrr99n/

Comment: Have you checked out my Demo? You just cannot use float on elements that are positioned: absolute, relative or fixed. You cannot want floating elements, while defining their position absolutely. Top and left property will position it at the same position inside the parent element every time.

Comment: Top is used in absolute, relative and fixed positioning. When you to add space to the top, you have to use margin or padding on the element. Have a look into this to get a better understanding of positioning with CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp